# Need a script to copy text from the script file to my clipboard

Tags: batch-file

Alright so I play a game called league of legends, and when you start a game you can search for you champion, you can search for multiple champions at the same time by separating their name by this "|". So I have made different lines of champions I play for each role, right now I have to manually copy/paste the text into the search bar. I would rather just double click a script file on my desktop and have it automatically copy the text to my clipboard.

Comment: the `clip` command is, what you look for. (`clip /?`)

Comment: Thank you but I know nothing about script languages could you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo Jack^^^|John^^^|Tom|clip
```

`echo` is the command to print something.

`@` supresses command repetition

`|` is a command of it's own (called "pipe" - it gives the output of the command before to the command behind)

`^^^|` tells the script to NOT execute the pipe symbol, but to print it as a char

All in all, this puts "Jack|John|Tom" into the clipboard.

Comment: Alright so I tried this and it doesn't seem to copy the text, it copies nothing from what I see, this is what I have @echo darius^|garen^|gnar^|jayce^|kayle^|malphite^|maokai^|nasus^|olaf^|pantheon^|renekton^|riven|clip

Comment: I underestimated escaping. Try again, please.